# Git repository is not cloning from remote server in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have my site working on server. I installed PhpStorm, set up FTP and SSH with my remote server and it works fine:

[image]

I go to `Git > Clone...`, enter URL of repository
`user@myremote.ftp.tools:/loudcar.com.ua/www/.git`
and enter FTP password.

But cloning is not working and I get an error "**does not appear to be a git repository**".

I expected repository cloned to my local server.

Comment: `ssh user@myremote.ftp.tools ls -l /` , `ssh user@myremote.ftp.tools ls -l /loudcar.com.ua` and so on…

Comment: @isherwood I verified path. Here is screenshot of console https://i.im.ge/2023/01/26/spZPsh.remote-server-loudcar.png

Comment: @phd https://i.im.ge/2023/01/26/spZPsh.remote-server-loudcar.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image the URL must be either

```
a50watt@myremote.ftp.tools:loudcar.com.ua/www/
```

or

```
a50watt@myremote.ftp.tools:/home/a50watt/loudcar.com.ua/www/
```

Comment: Exactly, second variant works fine, I had to specify /home/..
Project cloned.
Thank you, sir.

Answer (score -1):

In your local directory where you want to clone your repository, open Git bash or command prompt.

Then run the below commands for creating local repository.

```
git init
git clone <Your Remote Repository URL>
```

After pressing enter, Git will ask for authentication on a new pop up screen. Enter your credentials.

If logged in successfully, your remote repository will be cloned on your current directory in which Git bash/cmd is running.

Comment: Initialization is not necessary for cloning.